# How to get the camera rendered state with MuJoCo?

Tags: deep-learning, game-physics, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Can I get the camera rendered state from the point of view of agent’s eyes (as visual sensory data)?

I would like to obtain agent's eyes view as black and white image ~3 times/second. So it won't be on every simulation step. Is that possible?

Thanks for your help!